# How to output minimal binary using Data.Binary and Data.ByteString.Lazy?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

Minimal test code (bs.hs):

```
import qualified Data.Binary as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BSLC

main = do
    BSLC.putStr $ B.encode $ Pad $ BSLC.pack "xxx"

data Pad = Pad BSLC.ByteString
instance B.Binary Pad where
    put (Pad p) = do
        B.put p
    get = do
        p <- B.get
        return $ Pad p
```

And I get:

```
% runghc bs.hs | od -c
0000000   \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 003   x   x   x                    
0000013
% ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.2
```

I expect to get "xxx".  I have no idea how the first 8 bytes (7 x \0 + 1 x 003) come from.

Comment: It's the length of the ByteString as a 64-bit (8 byte) number.  If you want a specific format for your output, you should not be using the Binary class.

Comment: After rereading the documentation, makes sense.

I started looking at Data.Binary.Get and Data.Binary.Put but somehow ended up with using Data.Binary.

Comment: @DerekElkins since your comment answered the question, you should provide it as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

From my comment, the explanation of the output is that the format `Binary` currently uses for serializing `ByteString`s is to output the length as a 64-bit integer followed by the contents of the `ByteString`.

Generally, though, the `Binary` class is of limited use.  There's no guarantee of forward or backward compatibility, no mechanism to even allow for schema evolution, no standard or specification for the instances to allow cross-language interoperability.  It's really only useful if you want an opaque binary blob that you will only store temporarily and/or communicate with nodes that you have a high level of control over.  As a consumer, this is all you can expect of a `Binary` instance.  While there is no reason not to make a `Binary` instance for a type for which you create serialization code, if you offer any guarantees beyond the above you should probably (also) present it separately from the `Binary` class.  Ideally, as an instance of some class which communicates those extra guarantees, e.g. a class for serializing to a specific format such as [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/).

All this is only directed at the `Binary` class.  The rest of the `binary` package is quite useful for its intended purpose.